# Can I cast an Object as an Interface?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I would like to cast a generic object as an interface, but I get an "Operator not applicable to this operand type" (this code is part of a custom component where I attach different Entity classes to be opened by them).

```
procedure OpenNewEntity(EntityClass: TClass);
begin
  if not Supports(EntityClass, IEntity) then
    raise Exception.Create(EntityClass.ClassName + ' is not an Entity');

  (EntityClass.Create as IEntity).Open;
end;
```

I'm trying to use TClass instead of the real class that implements the interface because I don't want to add all the dependencies of that class to this unit.

Instead of TClass I have also tried to declare a class reference to classes implementing the interface, but it says "Class type required".

```
  TEntityClass = class of IEntity;
```

Can I use a new instance of an interface from a class that implements it without adding dependencies to those classes ?.

Comment: "Supports" is what I usually use to cast an object to an interface reference.  `Supports(EntityObj, IEntity, VarOfTypeIEntity)`.

Comment: Of course, IEntity needs to have a GUID.

Comment: @KenBourassa Thanks, I didn't know Support could do that. It's perfect for my case, if you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that won't work this way in most cases, because that would always call TObject.Create and not any constructor declared in the EntityClass.

A better approach would be to use Generics, which allows the compiler to catch any class that does not support `IEntity`:

```
type
  IEntity = interface
    ['{1B885059-58E5-4475-883F-6CD04FA01D40}']
    procedure Open;
  end;

type
  TEntityFactory = record
  public
    class function OpenNewEntity<T: constructor, IEntity>: IEntity; static;
  end;

class function TEntityFactory.OpenNewEntity<T>: IEntity;
begin
  Result := T.Create;
  Result.Open;
end;
```

The constraints put onto the Generic type `T` guarantees that the class has a parameterless constructor and supports `IEntity`.

**Update:**
As it turns out, you only have the class type in a variable, and thus cannot use the Generic approach. The tricky part is now to create the Entity instance in the appropriate way. Based on the code found in `TJSONUnMarshal.ObjectInstance()`, an implementation of your procedure could look like this:

```
procedure OpenNewEntity(EntityClass: TClass);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  entity: IEntity;
  instance: TObject;
  rType: TRttiType;
  mType: TRTTIMethod;
  metaClass: TClass;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  rType := ctx.GetType(EntityClass);
  if rType <> nil then
    begin
    for mType in rType.GetMethods do
    begin
      if mType.HasExtendedInfo and mType.IsConstructor and (Length(mType.GetParameters) = 0) then
      begin
        // invoke
        metaClass := rType.AsInstance.MetaclassType;
        instance := mType.Invoke(metaClass, []).AsObject;
        if not Supports(instance, IEntity, entity) then
          raise Exception.Create(EntityClass.ClassName + ' is not an Entity');
        entity.Open;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    raise Exception.Create(EntityClass.ClassName + ' has no parameterless constructor');
  end;
  raise Exception.Create(EntityClass.ClassName + ' has no runtime type information');
end;
```

Comment: That looks awesome @Uwe, but would you be so kind to show a sample of how to call the TEntityFactory ?. I'm not very used to generics, and I get a "Method 'NewEntity' requires explicit type arguments" when I try to call it like that :"`Entity := TEntityFactory.OpenNewEdit<FEntityClass>;`" (EntityClass is defined as TClass and contains a valid class that implements Entitty).

Comment: So you don't have the actual class type available for the call? In that case the generic approach may not be appropriate and you need to find a solution for the create problem. You should expand a bit describing more of your system to allow suggestions how to do that. Is there a common ancestor for these classes?

Comment: No, at that point I only have a a reference to the actual class. I'm building a TEntityAction (derived from TAction), with a new property EntityClass of type TClass (I don't want the component to have dependencies on the actual classes), So now I can assign those Actions to the main cxRibbon items and they'll open their corresponding Entity, unless you have assigned a OnExecute event indicating that you want to open manually the Entity (to assign parameters, ...). I basically use those TEntityActions to link my Entities and the cxRibbon items, and interact how to open them.

Comment: Then you will have problems creating the instances calling the appropriate constructor. There is a way using extended RTTI for that. As a start you can find such an implementation in TJSONUnMarshal.ObjectInstance.

Comment: Thanks, calling EntityClass.Create seems to work fine. It's when I try to cast the new instance as Entity to call the Open method that it doesn't allow that casting. I will check the class that you quoted, and I will also check to just not do that casting and just call the Open method through Rtti.

Comment: I added an example using RTTI.